# How can I improve this master detail/grouping UI?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, interface, human-interface-guideline, screen-real-estate

In my application, I have to represent a Work Order entity that has N Work Order Sections and each section has M sub-items. Currently, I'm representing this like so:

[image]

Each Work Order has a bunch of fields (not shown). Then I've got a tab strip showing the sections, and each section has fields (not shown) and the M items.

I'm using tabs to indicate N children, and an extra dummy tab to add a new entity to the list. And I'm using a link to enable deleting the *current* entity in the list.

I'm trying to find a more elegant and unified way to represent the **Add New** and **Delete Current** actions, keeping them physically together. What would be a good way of doing this?

Or, is there an entirely different and better way of capturing these master detail relationships?

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be:

- keep the tabs on the left,
- use background color for the selected tab same as the inner box border color,
- separate groups of digits, e.g. `1000-054`,
- use a gray `x` on each tab, which would be highlighted on hover to a red `x`,
- and a `+` sign on the bottom tab

there are plenty of inspirations for [vertical tabs](https://www.google.cz/search?tbm=isch&q=vertical+tabs), [close tab](https://www.google.cz/search?tbm=isch&q=close+tab), [add new tab](https://www.google.cz/search?tbm=isch&q=add+new+tab)

or you can consider [miller columns](https://www.google.cz/search?tbm=isch&q=miller+columns) or some special visualization for a [hierarchical tree](https://www.google.cz/search?tbm=isch&q=hierarchical+tree)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all comments from Aprillion except the one about the x-button in each tab to delete.

The x-action on each would be more suited if you're just closing the tab. This is more suited in scenarios where data is more fleeting, and easily recovered (like a web browser).

In the case of work items, a delete action is more permanent and it would be good if it got a location and mechanism suited to the metaphor. I would place a delete button (with perhaps a garbage can icon) in the right corner of the tab-content.

A confirm action or undo-able notification box would be nice.
You could also move the 'EDIT' option there and have an 'option-panel' in the top right.